# Algebraic Combinatorics about a Finite Graph

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

Here is a problem listed on a book 'Algebraic Combinatorics' by Richard P.Stanley.

> Let $G$ be a finite graph with at least two vertices. Suppose that for some $l \ge 1$, the number of walks of length $l$ between any two vertices $u, v$(including $u=v$) is odd.
>
> Show that there is a nonempty subset $S$ of the vertices such that $S$ has an even number of elements and such that every vertex $v$ of $G$ is adjacent to an even number of vertices in $S$. (A vertex is adjacent to itself if and only if there is a loop at $v$.)

I really couldn't get the gist of it, so the title became quite vague as well.

What I got from it was that if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$, then all components of $A^l$ is odd. I tried induction, proving the contraposition but I just got baffled. I also could understand that a graph derived from $S$ has an adjacency matrix that can fit inside $A$, but I don't know what to do afterwards.

Maybe I have to use more linear algebraic stuff or turn to combinatorial way?

Comment: The hypothesis is that for some $\ell$, _some_ entry of $A^\ell$ is odd.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil An entry of $A^l$ represents the number of length $l$ walks so I think for some $l$, every entry should be odd. If not, that means for some two vertices $u, v$ the number of walks between the two is even. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are right. I misread what you wrote. So for some $\ell$, each entry of $A^\ell$ is odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at everything modulo $2$. The matrix $A^l$ is singular, and so for some $v$, $Av=0$. This gives the second property. The first one follows from $A^lv=0$.

Comment: I could understand up to $Av=0$. Could you tell me how this implies the existence of a subset $S$ such that every vertex $v$ of $G$ is adjacent to an even number of vertices in $S$? What does $Av=0$ in modulo 2 implies in general here?

Comment: $v$ is the characteristic vector of $S$.